# Parameter index out of range (0 < 1)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I know this question has been asked many times here on stackoverflow, however I still can't pinpoint the exact reason on why my code is not working.

This is the query:

```
String QUERY = "INSERT INTO orders (user, product_id, final_price, key_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Manually running the query using the same parameters that I use on my failing function works perfectly.

This is the preparedStatement:

```
// ...more code up here...
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionManager.databaseConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY);

preparedStatement.setInt(1, user_id);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, product_id);
preparedStatement.setFloat(3, _finalprice);
// ...more code down there...
preparedStatement.setInt(4, _keyid);
```

The error I'm getting is the following:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ).
```

I have several other INSERTs done with the same technique and they all work flawlessly, I'm starting to think that there is some problem with the mysqlconnector I'm using (mysql-connector-java-8.0.19).

Full code for context:

```
private static boolean assignProduct(int product_id, int user_id)
{
    String QUERY = "INSERT INTO orders (user, product_id, final_price, key_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
    
    float _finalprice = 0;
    int _discount = 0;
    int _keyid = 0;
    
    if(product_id <= 0 || user_id <= 0) {return false;} 
    
    Product _p;
    try {
        _p = Product_utils.productByID(product_id);
    
        if(_p != null)
        {
            _finalprice = _p.getPrice();
            _discount = _p.getDiscount();
        
            if(_discount > 0)
            {
                _finalprice = _finalprice - (_finalprice * _discount / 100);
            }
        }else { return false;}
    
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connectionManager.databaseConnection.prepareStatement(QUERY);

        
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, user_id);
        preparedStatement.setInt(2, product_id);
        preparedStatement.setFloat(3, _finalprice);
    
        _keyid = retriveKey(product_id);
    
        if(_keyid == 0) { return false; } 
    
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, _keyid);
    
        if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate() == 1) {return true;} else {return false;} 
    
    } catch (SQLException e) { System.out.println(e.toString()); return false;}
}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? Are you getting an error? Is the orders table just not getting updated?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the exact error(s) you're getting and a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (0 < 1 ). Apparently my parameters are not recognized.

Comment: I suspect that the code you think you're running isn't what you're actually running. I would set a breakpoint on the line that causes the exception (or set a breakpoint exception, if you can) and see what the statement is at that point.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is there. Now I will add the full code, I also used breakpoints and variable watcher, user_id, product_id, _finalprice and _keyid values are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by upgrading my mysql connector to 8.0.20